# I would like to wipe my encrypted HD and start all over (kubuntu)

Tags: kubuntu, encryption

I did something stupid!  I forgot my password on a new install.  I went on a small vacation and came back and you know the rest.  What's the easiest and quickest way for me to wipe the install?  I don't even have a DVD.  I installed this with a USB drive and downloaded the software from that.  There's nothing I need to save or get to on this install.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.  Also I'm a noobie, so try to be kind.

Comment: Just use the same USB drive, there is an option to delete everything and install.

Answer (score 1):

I assume by the fact that you're asking ths question that you no longer have the live usb drive you used originally?

The easiest way would be to pop down to your local supermarket, grab a Linux Format (o other) magazine with a coverdisk.

If you're lucky, Kubuntu will be one of this month's live distros. If not, just use one of them to download the distro of your choice and you can then install it the way you did in the first place.

If you encrypt your drive again my advice would be to keep a copy of the password somewhere (sometimes I'll even email them to myself so I can search on my phone)
Yes, it reduces security slightly but security can be a hindrance when you forget a password and sometimes you have to balance risk with usefulness.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I do have the USB boot drive.  The thing is it's not that easy to get around to this setting to format the drive.  I have 4 options on this USB drive.

*Ubuntu
Advanced options for Ubuntu
Memory test (memtest86+)
Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)

From just doing a little deduction and selecting the first two options, and the first two options doesn't give anything near "formatting the disc".

The 1st option takes me to logging in with name and password.  Thanks!
The 2nd option gives 4 new options and nothing near "formatting the drive" and starting over.

The 4 options here is 
*Ubuntu, with Linux 4.8.0-41-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.8.0-41 generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.8.0-36-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.8.0-41-generic (recovery mode)

I'm sorry but none of these sound like these will get me a clean disc to start my install over again.

So basically I'm at the start of my post and nowhere to turn.

Comment: You can't format the hard disk you've booted from. Regardless of what option you select while booting you won't be able to format the disk. You can format partitions but without the capability to reinstall (USB or dvd for example) then you're no better off. Any install media will allow you to format during the install so I would start by getting a hold of an install USB or dvd

Comment: I have a USB boot drive.  It's what I used to install Ubuntu.  What I am quoting above is from the USB boot drive.  Is there anyway to format the HD with this USB boot drive?

Comment: I sounds like your pc is still booting from the hard drive rather than from the USB. When you boot up do you get anything flash up on screen that says something like `F** - boot options` before you get to the part where you get to choose Ubuntu or Memory Test etc? 

What model is your pc?